# Which query is causing Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: php, mysql, deadlock

I cannot figure out which Query is causing `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.
My wrapper for mysql has the following lines

```
if (mysql_errno($this->conn) == 1213) {
  $this->bug_log(0,"Deadlock. SQL:".$this->sql);
}
```

where `bug_log` writes to a file.

The bug log file has no Deadlock errors, but `/var/log/mysqld.log` has multiple records:

```
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
111016  3:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
```

How can i track it down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An update with WHERE clause which is not by unique column will cause deadlock if another transaction waits for the current transaction to complete. Here's a quick test:

```
CREATE TABLE test (pk int PRIMARY KEY, a int);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (0, 0);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 0);
```

Session 1

```
BEGIN;
SELECT a FROM test WHERE pk=0 FOR UPDATE;
```

Session 2

```
BEGIN;
SELECT a FROM test WHERE pk=0 FOR UPDATE;
```

(Session 2 is now blocked)

Session 1

```
UPDATE test SET a=1 WHERE a>0;
```

In session 2 we receive an error

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

If in the WHERE clause of the update we use the pk column only, the error does not occur.

Comment: What do you mean "use the pk column only" ? That's what you're doing in your example, isn't it?

Comment: nope - in the WHERE clause of the update I have "a>0". If I write "pk=0" there (or anything that uses only unique columns), I don't receive the error.

Comment: I think this is the first time I actually understood deadlocks vs plain blocks.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this occur on one or more of the following conditions:

1. Joining on the same table multiple times in a query (SELF JOIN)
2. When using transactions that contain queries that manipulate the same table in multiple ways concurrently
3. When using transactions and using the same table as a SELF JOIN or a Sub-query

It can be difficult to track down but the situation is basically saying one query is preventing another from running which in turn prevents the first from finishing etc...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: I do have a nested query, but not on self. How can it be that it causes a deadlock every single time?

Comment: Are you using transactions? This can also result if two transactions are working on the same table but different key words. Like `UPDATE TABLE ... WHERE group_id=X AND user_id=Y` and `UPDATE TABLE ... WHERE  user_id=Y AND group_id=X` assuming these ere different keys. You can see that if they ran at the same time they'd lock the other index for the other query to return, resulting in a deadlock. I'd check your queries and make sure they are written in the same order when dealing with any INDEXES.

Comment: could be, but how would I find the other querry? Currently I tracked this query for deadlock: `UPDATE players SET chatban = chatban - 1 WHERE recent=1 and chatban > 0` how can this be?

Comment: Find all other queries using players and compare the queries. Perhaps you are selecting one with WHERE chatban>0 AND recent=1 which would cause it.